# If $\emptyset$ denotes the empty set, what is $ \langle \emptyset \rangle$ in an group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If  $\emptyset$ denotes the  empty set, what is $\langle \emptyset \rangle$ in a group?

Would it just be $\emptyset$? or none?

Comment: Which group?  Is $\emptyset$ an element of the group?  Are you trying to look at the set generated by the element $\emptyset$ or are you trying to look at the set that would have been generated by a collection of elements but in the case that you had provided none?

Comment: The notation $\langle X\rangle$  is often used to denote the subgroup (of some group $G$) generated by the subset $X$ of $G$, i.e., the smallest subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $X\subseteq H$. Then $\langle \varnothing\rangle$ would denote the subgroup consisting of just the identity element of $G$.

Comment: Elaborating on Andreas Blass' comment: there is a notion of generation in [**universal algebra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra), where in an algebra $A$ the set $\langle X\rangle$ (for $X\subseteq A$) is the set of elements of $A$ which (informally speaking) can be built from elements of $X$ via the function symbols of $A$ (formally speaking: the smallest subalgebra containing $X$). If the algebra('s language) has nullary function symbols (= constant symbols) then $\langle\emptyset\rangle$ is nonempty since it contains the elements corresponding to those symbols. (continued)

Comment: This is one example (of many) of how the choice of language can matter. There are three natural languages for groups: the group operation $*$ alone, the group operation and the identity element $e$, or the group operation, the identity element, and the inverse operation. In the first language we get $\langle\emptyset\rangle=\emptyset$, while in the second and third languages we get $\langle\emptyset\rangle=\{e\}$. (Incidentally, another difference: groups form a [variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) in the sense of the third language but not the first or second.)

Comment: (I'm fudging here re: whether we accept "empty algebras" in the first place. But, meh.)

Comment: I know I've seen $\langle a\rangle$ to be used rather than $\langle \{a\}\rangle$ so the notation is potentially ambiguous, hence my question.